# Is there any program for Linux to layout and generate directory structure?

Tags: linux, directories, data-structure

I need to generate folder structure for organizing my $HOME folder. Of course, I can write big shell script with `mkdir -p` on every line but maybe there are more user-friendly solution for creating directory structure? For example, using nested structure I can write some file and somehow process it:

```
- Downloads
    - Music
    - Movies
- University
    - First year
        - English
        - Maths
    - Second year
...
```

and so on. But that's just an example, I don't know if any such tools exist and how they works. I tried searching on Github but found nothing.

Comment: Maybe you do not get the idea of `mkdir -p`. If you exec `mkdir -p University/"First year"/English` this will create the entire tree University, the Unibersity/"FIrst year" then University/"First year"/English. So you need to have only edge elements: Misic, Movies, English, Math....

Comment: What about `tree` command ?

Comment: Is there any point to creating a bunch of empty folders? You might want to take a look at a file manager called ranger. It makes file management a lot easier.